# How to unnest deeply nested objects recursively?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am working with an array that could have a number of objects/arrays of *unpredictable* nesting. Each of the objects will always have a `name` property, and some of these objects may have an array of `sub_fields`. I wish to strip down the object so that each object's key equals the `name` property, while maintaining the levels of nesting from the original.

Here's an example of what I could be starting off with:

```
var data = [
    {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        name: 'Object 1'
    },
    {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        name: 'Object 2'
    },
    {
        foo: 'foo',
        bar: 'bar',
        name: 'Object 3',
        sub_fields : [
            {
                foo: 'foo',
                bar: 'bar',
                name: 'SubLevel Object 1',
                sub_fields: [
                    {
                        foo: 'foo',
                        bar: 'bar',
                        name: 'SubLevel Object 1',
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                foo: 'foo',
                bar: 'bar',
                name: 'SubLevel Object 2',
                sub_fields: [
                    {
                        foo: 'foo',
                        bar: 'bar',
                        name: 'SubLevel Object 1',
                    },
                    {
                        foo: 'foo',
                        bar: 'bar',
                        name: 'SubLevel Object 2',
                    },
                    {
                        foo: 'foo',
                        bar: 'bar',
                        name: 'SubLevel Object 3',
                        sub_fields: [
                            {
                                foo: 'foo',
                                bar: 'bar',
                                name: 'SubLevel Object 1'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Ideally, I'm aiming to take that original data and create something like this:

```
var newData = {
    'Object 1': null,
    'Object 2': null,
    'Object 3': {
        'Sublevel Object 1': {
            'Sublevel Object 1': null
        },
        'Sublevel Object 2': {
            'Sublevel Object 1': null,
            'Sublevel Object 2': null,
            'Sublevel Object 3': {
                  'Sublevel Object 1': null
             }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like I've been spending way too much time on this when I know there must be some kind of recursive function to make it happen --- I'm just a bit too inexperienced with the sort of thing that I'm struggling to find the solution.

Can someone please show me what I could do?

**EDIT**
Here's what I've tried. It's a jumbled mess and way too piecemeal --- embarrassing in fact haha --- but, in good faith, I didn't want you to think I haven't been trying to figure this out on my own:

(also, the "field_group" being parsed is from a more relevant JSON data that I'm working with... not the above "foo/bar" example.)

```
var parsed_field_group = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(field_group));
var fields = field_group[0].fields;

function removeKeys(obj, keys) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            switch(typeof(obj[prop])) {
                case 'object':
                    if(keys.indexOf(prop) > -1) {
                        delete obj[prop];
                    } else {
                        removeKeys(obj[prop], keys);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    if(!keys.includes(prop)) {
                        delete obj[prop];
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

removeKeys(fields, ['name', 'wrapper'])

console.log(fields)

var newJson = Object.create(null);
fields.forEach(field => {
    if (field.hasOwnProperty('sub_fields')) {
        newJson[field.name] = field
    } else {
        newJson[field.name] = null
    }
})

function handleSubFields(obj, key) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj[prop]) {
            obj[prop][key].forEach(field => {
                if (field.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    obj[prop][field.name] = field
                } else {
                    obj[prop][field.name] = null
                }
            })
            delete obj[prop][key]
            delete obj[prop].name
        }
    }
}
handleSubFields(newJson, 'sub_fields')

console.log(newJson)
```

The above has gotten me very close, but I end up getting stuck on the sub_fields nested inside of an object's first sub_field.

I know the above must be laughable. Please be kind! :-)

Comment: If it's not a string, it's **not** [JSON](http://json.org)

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?  It doesn't have to work or be complete, we just like to see a good-faith effort first.  And Andreas is correct, what you have in the question is not JSON, you have an object literal expression.

Comment: I wrote a solution, and noticed, that your expected result is odd for `"Sublevel Object 3": null`, because the input has a `sub_fields` there.

Comment: @Andreas `If it's not a string, it's not JSON` You may want to clarify that statement. Boolean and numbers are valid JSON entities for example

Comment: @Amy I've edited my question/request above to show you what I tried.

Comment: @ASDFGerte good catch. I've made the edit.

Comment: Ok, here is the code that made me notice this: `const t = o => o.reduce((p, c) => (p[c.name] = c.sub_fields ? t(c.sub_fields) : null, p), {});` (may fail for edge cases, didn't consider everything)

Comment: @customcommander _"JSON is a **text syntax** that facilitates structured data interchange between all programming language. ... JSON syntax describes a  **sequence of Unicode code points**."_ ([ECMA-404](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf))

Comment: @Andreas Perhaps I'm misunderstanding then but you seemed to imply that `{"foo": true}` isn't valid JSON, even though it is. Perhaps you're confusing the notation and the string representation as returned by `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: @customcommander `JSON.parse({ toString: () => ({}) });`. Yes, that's exactly the case. `{"foo": true}` is not valid json (as javascript object). JSON has to be a string. `JSON.parse` just does an automatic `ToString` on the argument as first step, because javascribbidies loves implicit conversions.

Comment: @customcommander `JSON.stringify()` (it's even in the name of the property) returns [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). `JSON.parse()` converts a string (that has to be valid JSON) back into actual JavaScript data types (e.g. numbers, booleans, strings, objects, ...). And we're back at my first comment: Anything that isn't a string is not JSON. `{ "foo": true } // object`, `"{ \"foo\": true }" // string that is also valid JSON`

Comment: As a note: `JSON.parse({"foo": true})` obviously also fails, because `"[object Object]"` is invalid json. It was just to show, that `JSON.parse` indeed first tries to convert to string, because JSON has to be a string.

Comment: @Andreas I don't necessarily disagree but I'm not sure this is the full story. What do you make up of this statement on MDN then: `array is also valid JSON` See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON

Comment: @customcommander They aren't referring to elements within the data structure.  They mean the *entire thing* is string content.  If you have a file called `data.json` that contains JSON data, that entire file is considered a string for Andrea's comments, because the file itself is text content, not binary.  When that file is read into code, it will be a string which can then be parsed into a corresponding JS object structure.

Comment: @Amy Ah right I see, fair enough. I think most people would acknowledge that `{"foo": true}` in a json file is in a textual format and not in a binary one. Hence why I was confused. But that's coming from a practical point of view, point taken nonetheless.

Comment: @customcommander Yeah, saying "JSON is a string" isn't *entirely* accurate; more accurate would be "JSON is text containing a well-defined structure".  We say it's a string because, when working with it in any programming language, it *is* a string.  Object literal expressions are commonly and incorrectly referred to as JSON, but because they aren't a string, it isn't actually JSON.  In the case of this question, the object keys aren't in double quotes, which is required for JSON, but not for object literal expressions.  JSON is literally the string representation of a JS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is very easy using recursion. Here is your basic case:

- You receive something that's not an object - you return `null`.

Then your basic recursion case:

- You receive an object, you construct a new object with a property the `name` of the object, the value being the recursive application of the function.

Finally, you just have to handle what happens if you have arrays:

- Walk the entire array and call the function against each element. Collect all results into the same object.

```js
var data = [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'Object 1' }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'Object 2' }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'Object 3', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1', }] }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 2', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1', }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 2', }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 3', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1' }] } ] } ] } ]


function toObj(data) {
  if (data == null) return null;
  
  //collect all recursive calls to the function in the same object
  if (Array.isArray(data))
    return data.reduce((acc, data) => ({ ...acc, ...toObj(data)}), {})
  
  //produce a new object from the `name` property and a recursive application of the function
  return { [data.name]: toObj(data.sub_fields, {}) };
}

console.log(toObj(data))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is way more elegant and concise than what I was attempting. Proves that I have a LOT to learn. I'm really grateful for you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2):

To transform

```
{ foo: 'foo'
, bar: 'bar'
, name: 'Object 1'
}
```

into:

```
{ 'Object 1': null
}
```

You can use this function:

```
const transform =
  ({name}) =>
    ({[name]: null});
```

**What if it contains `sub_fields`?**

Instead of assigning `null`, assign the result of applying `transform` to all objects in `sub_fields`.

We can modify `transform` to support that:

```
const transform =
  ({name, sub_fields}) =>
    ( { [name]: sub_fields
          ? Object.assign({}, ...sub_fields.map(transform))
          : null
      }
    );
```

Now you can apply the same principle to our array to produce your final object:

```js
const transform =
  ({name, sub_fields}) =>
    ( { [name]: sub_fields
          ? Object.assign({}, ...sub_fields.map(transform))
          : null
      }
    );
    
    
console.log(

  Object.assign({}, ...data.map(transform))

);
```

```html
<script>
const data = [{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"Object 1"},{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"Object 2"},{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"Object 3","sub_fields":[{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"SubLevel Object 1","sub_fields":[{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"SubLevel Object 1"}]},{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"SubLevel Object 2","sub_fields":[{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"SubLevel Object 1"},{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"SubLevel Object 2"},{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"SubLevel Object 3","sub_fields":[{"foo":"foo","bar":"bar","name":"SubLevel Object 1"}]}]}]}];
</script>
```

Comment: Any strong reason for `{ [name]: !sub_fields ? null : Object.assign({}, ...sub_fields.map(transform))}` over `{ [name]: sub_fields ? Object.assign({}, ...sub_fields.map(transform)) : null}`.  I find the `!` more difficult to notice.

Answer (score 1):

There are already several good answers, and a nice exposition from customcommander.  I think this alternative is worth consideration for several reasons:

- I choose `reduce` only if something more explicit is not available.  While it is the most powerful of the array iteration methods, it's lower level and to me it's not as self-documenting as this combination of `map` and `Object.assign`.  (This is even more important in comparison with `forEach`, which has no inherent semantics at all.)
- I have a personal preference for working with expressions rather than statements, and prefer a single-expression arrow function to one with one or more `return` statements.
- While customcommander's exposition is great, and I like the technique a lot, the `transform` function still needs a wrapper to get the expected output.  There is absolutely nothing wrong with wrappers (although I would add another function for that.)  But the version I propose here manages the same thing with similar techniques and no added complexity without needing a wrapper.

```js
const transform = (obj) =>
  Array .isArray (obj)
    ? Object .assign (...obj .map (transform))
    : {[obj .name] : 'sub_fields' in obj ? transform (obj .sub_fields) : null}

const data = [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'Object 1' }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'Object 2' }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'Object 3', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1', }] }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 2', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1', }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 2', }, { foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 3', sub_fields: [{ foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar', name: 'SubLevel Object 1' }] } ] } ] } ]

console .log (transform (data))
```

I don't mean to suggest that there is anything wrong with the other solutions, only that this combination of factors meant that there was room for one more technique.

Comment: Wouldn't you mutate the first element in `...obj.map(transform)` if you don't merge into an empty object first?

Comment: It would, but that's a throw-away object anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I develop this function using recursion to achive your goal, knowing that in your object always going to be an attribute called 'name', and occasionaly other called 'sub_fields'.

```
function rebuildNameObject(objArr = [], resObj = {}){
  objArr.forEach(obj => {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(item => {
          if (item === 'name'){
            resObj[obj[item]] = null;
          }

          if(item === 'sub_fields'){
            resObj[obj['name']] = rebuildNameObject(obj[item]);
          }

        });
    });
  return resObj;
}
```